# group and collect set if columns are not empty after join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a table and 3 dictionaries. The dictionaries have only 1 column each. The table's structure is

```
time:string, ctn:string, url:string
```

after joining I get a df with 6 columns

```
tableDF
.join(enq2, $"url".contains($"q2"), "left_outer")
.join(enq3, $"url".contains($"q3"), "left_outer")
.join(model, $"url".contains($"model"), "left_outer")
```

What I need is 3 columns from the table and, in case `q2, q3, and model` are not null, a set of `model`. Or in case either of `q2, q3 or model` is null an empty set.

so I group

```
.groupBy($"url", $"ctn", $"timestamp")
```

and try to get the set

```
.withColumn("model",
when($"q2".isNotNull && $"q3".isNotNull && $"model".isNotNull, collect_set($"model")
).otherwise())
```

which doesn't work

I also tried

```
.agg(get_set($"q2", $"q3", $"model").alias("model"))
```

where get_set looks somewhat like

```
def get_set(q2: ColumnName, q3: ColumnName, model: ColumnName):Column={
if(q2.isNotNull && q3.isNotNull && model.isNotNull)
  collect_set(model)
}
```

but `isNotNull` returns `Column` and I need `boolean` for this. I'm not sure if `==null` is right. Or maybe I should convert column to string and check it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing the following

```
.groupBy($"url", $"ctn", $"timestamp").
agg(
  collect_set(
    when($"q2".isNotNull && $"q3".isNotNull && $"model".isNotNull, $"model").
    otherwise(lit(null))
  )
)
```

or you can just `drop` the nulled rows

```
df_joined.na.drop().groupBy($"url", $"ctn", $"timestamp").
agg(collect_set($"model"))
```

Comment: The first fails with `IllegalArgumentException: Missing required char ':' at 'struct<url:string,ctn:string,timestamp:string,collect_set^(CASE WHEN (((q2 IS NOT NULL) AND (q3 IS NOT NULL)) AND (model IS NOT NULL)) THEN model END):array<string>>'` And I'm not sure about the 2. Wouldn't it collect values in a set even if q2 and q3 are null?

Comment: no the condition is that all three shouldn't be null for collect_set to have values and if any one is null no values would collected as set. The second one with na.drop should work for you. didn't the second one work?

Comment: I don't need to drop the rows with null values thought. I need an empty set there. Edited the question so it's clearer.

Comment: The mistake changed a little, byt overwise remained the same. `Missing required char ':' at 'struct<url:string,ctn:string,timestamp:string,collect_set^(CASE WHEN (((q2 IS NOT NULL) AND (q3 IS NOT NULL)) AND (model IS NOT NULL)) THEN model ELSE NULL END):array<string>>'`

Comment: There wasn't a problem in logic. Looks like the mistake was happening when I tried writing the dataframe to disk. Adding `.alias("model")` after collect_set helped. Thanks.